# Android Track Location Issue

Tags: android, gps, location

I am working on app in which I have to calculate the total distance from start point to end point. I use the Location Manager of the Android SDK, use location listener and use both provider(GPS and network provider) and in every 20 seconds I have track the location and put the tracked location into the array list. After a time period calculate the total distance by

```
total distance = dist at point[0,1]+ dist at point[1,2] + ... +dist at point[n-1,n]
```

where `0,1,2,...,n` is the index of array list location value.

After several test, Not got the accurate result. Approximately 60-70% of actual odometer value. Please guide if have some other alternative to be used. 
Please guide me how I got more accurate result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS and network location both have a degree of uncertainty associated with them, so neither will generally give you an exact distance when compared to something like an odometer.  If you're outdoors and not in urban canyons, GPS will generally give you a better distance estimate than network location.

Underestimates of distance (what you're seeing) is probably due to your sampling rate (every 20 secs) or lost GPS signals.  I'd try increasing your sampling rate to once every 4 seconds or so, and make sure your GPS unit isn't losing a fix.  GPS sensitivity can vary widely across devices, so try to test with a few different Android devices.  You can also check out an Android app I developed to help measure GPS accuracy on Android devices:
http://www.gpsbenchmark.com/

Overestimates of distance are generally caused by GPS noise, or the position bouncing around due to small (and sometimes large) GPS position error.  Kalman filters are a good way to reduce the impact of some of this noise.  You can also try to filter the path and reduce some of the detail via line simplification.  An implementation of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm to do this is available under Apache 2.0 in the MyTracks project:
http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/util/LocationUtils.java#78

Comment: Barbeau, As explain above my method is right or not.(total distance = dist at point[0,1]+ dist at point[1,2] + ... +dist at point[n-1,n]. If there is any other method. Let me know please.

Comment: I think this is what you're method is doing: For a set of points A through Z, total_distance = dist(A to B) + dist(B to C) + dist(C to D)... + dist(Y to Z).  This is correct for computing the total distance given a set of geographic coordinates, although as stated above it can give under or over-estimates based on GPS error and sampling rates.  An example using the Location.distanceTo method - http://goo.gl/U7vJM - would be total_distance = A.distanceTo(B) + B.distanceTo(C) + C.distanceTo(D)... + Y.distanceTo(Z).

Comment: Thanks Barbeau. I am always appreciate your Great Help :)